# Implementation of a generic for graph connectivity algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, functional-programming, graph-algorithm

I have an interface for an object factory that creates graphs from a collection of objects given a vertex creation `Function<Object,Vertex>` and a linking `BiPredicate<Vertex,Vertex>`.

This design allows for the specification of arbitrary graph connectivity algorithms by supplying both of these functions, but as far as I've been able to implement it, this comes at the cost of having to loop over all pairs of objects in the input collection like this (classes `Graph` and `Vertex` are defined elsewhere):

```
Function<Object,Vertex> maker; // defined by user.
BiPredicate<Vertex,Vertex> linker; // defined by user.

Graph makeGraph( Collection<Object> input ) {
    Graph g = new Graph();
    Collection<Vertex> vertices = input.stream.map( ( Objec t ) -> maker.apply( t ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    for( Vertex ego : vertices ) {
        Collection<Vertex> alters = new ArrayList<>();
        alters.addAll( vertices );
        alters.remove( ego );
        for( Vertex alter : alters ) {
            if( linker.test( ego, alter ) ) {
                g.makeEdge( ego, alter );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I actually have two questions:

1. is there a more elegant way of iterating over all possible pairs (i,j) in a collection than my ugly solution of creating a new list, copying everything and removing i from the copy?
2. can anybody think of a way of optimizing that double iteration? Right now the execution time for this is O( n^2 ) in the best case, because the implementation needs to accept a linking function without any knowledge about it, but maybe there are ways around this? e.g. specifying certain parameters to indicate, for example, that the iteration can break after the first failure of the linker test for a co-occurrence network, etc.

Of course, if anyone can think of an alternative way of going about this, I'd be happy to hear it.

EDIT:

Forget the first question, Robert Navado's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420872/1386105) made me realize that I was wrong.

In order to clarify then: I am looking for a way of telling an implementation that the application of the linker function can be optimized under certain conditions (e.g. In the co-occurrence example mentioned above, "sort by position and break after first negative result").

Answer (score 1):

Well, until you can have unlinked vertexes in your graph in the graph and your graph is sparse, I would suggest to store edges rather than Vertexes.
However maximum number of edges in single-linked clique is V*(V-1). So in worse case you'll need O(V^2) iterations to link your graph and even more for multigraph.

As for iterations syntax the following should work as well:

```
for(Vertex alter : vertices )
   for(Vertex ego : vertices ){
       //Do the descision
}
```

Take a look on the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) library for graph manipulation. It's probably outdated, but you can take a look at their data structures for inspiration.

Comment: Woa. Thanks for the reality check; I don't know why I thought that the iteration had to remove the pair (i,i) from iteration, which is actually an error, implementations may want loops, so I actually have to check for them.

Also, the interface is particularly supposed to make no assumptions about whether multiple edges are allowed... that should be defined in the linker function. I think my question needs some revision. I'll go edit.